# Как получить int значения из SQL-запроса

Tags: c#, mysql

Как получить число (`int`), полученное в результате такого SQL-запроса:

```
SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE name="name"
```

Получается выводить только с применением `foreach`, что очень громоздко:

```
SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
foreach (DbDataRecord item in reader)
{  
    intvalue = Convert.ToInt32(item["id"]);  
}
```

Видимо так более правильно, потому что заработала функция `MAX`

Comment: А что громоздкого в `foreach`, тело которого состоит из одной строки?

Comment: Я, если честно, думал что можно как то обратиться напрямую к reader'у

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using(SQLiteDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
  while (reader.Read())
  {
    intvalue = Convert.ToInt32(reader["id"]);
  }
}
```